# Claim a specific failing test in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, phpunit, jenkins-plugins

One team I am working on uses Jenkins + PHPUnit for CI.  I am looking for a good way to indicate a particular person is addressing a particular test which may be failing the build.  The [Claim plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Claim+plugin) seems great for claiming an entire failing build but I'm looking for some way to make it more granular. It would be particularly useful to make a "sticky" per-test claim so if the same test fails next build the Claimer is retained.  Can Claim do this (I thought it could, but I must be missing something if so)?  Can something else do this?

Comment: The feature you're looking for is part of the claim plugin. As soon as claiming and publishing the junit test results is activated for a project, test specific claiming is allowed. As I am not a PHP developer I cannot verify this suggestion: Have you tried to install the [xunit plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin)? If so, please drill down to a specific test result of a broken test and verify if you can claim the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is provided by the Claim plugin, as indicated by MrsTang. However, you need to activate this per job.

In the Job configuration, under the Post-Build Action `Publish Test Results` you will find a check box `Allow claiming of failed tests`. That will allow you to claimed failed tests. We found that feature to work quite fine.

Comment: Interesting.  I see that checkbox if I add 'Publish JUnit test result' but not under 'Publish xUnit test result' (I'm using PHP here).  Perhaps xUnit does not support this feature yet.

Comment: I think the feature is not provided by the JUnit plugin, but by the Claim plugin. I would suggest creating an issue in the Jenkins Jira for the Claim plugin, requesting to add the option to xUnit plugin as well.